# can IIS SMTP server receive messages?

Tags: iis, smtp

I need an SMTP server to be able to accept EMails. I have a custom written socket listener but wanted to use somethign more robust and less home grown. I wanted to try to get IIS to capture inbound SMTP messages and save them to disk so that i can use a service to read them from disk and parse them into a SQL DB.

Is it possible to get IIS to receive SMTP messages, and if so how (i came up at a loss using Google)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the following should get you started - http://support.frontrange.com/support/gmsm-gmce/6.x/IIS6POP_smtpwithGM.pdf.